# DocuSign Connect with NodeJS w/ Express

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I'm having trouble extracting data from the response I get from Connect. I can see that the endpoint is getting two POSTs, but I don't see the data because console.log(req) reports everything and I can't find the information.

I'm using ngrok to expose my endpoints and I have Connect configured to send documents with the XML update on an envelope signing.

To state the question, how would you pull a document out of the request?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I used util to output the entire req and still can't find which object the XML and document bytes are in. It's certainly not the body.

```
{ _readableState: 
   { highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: false,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     calledRead: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     objectMode: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _maxListeners: 10,
  socket: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        reading: true },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        close: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [],
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     onend: [Function],
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 32864,
     _bytesDispatched: 25,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _connections: 2,
        connections: [Getter/Setter],
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _connectionKey: 'ip' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        onend: [Function],
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 1246,
        _bytesDispatched: 751,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _idleStart: 1433278153744,
        parser: [Object],
        ondata: [Function],
        _paused: false,
        _httpMessage: null },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
     _idleStart: 1433278184434,
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
        onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function] },
     ondata: [Function],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _headerSent: false,
        _header: '',
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _expect_continue: true,
        _sent100: true,
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {} } },
  connection: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        reading: true },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        close: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [],
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     onend: [Function],
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 32864,
     _bytesDispatched: 25,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _connections: 2,
        connections: [Getter/Setter],
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _connectionKey: 'ip' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        onend: [Function],
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 1246,
        _bytesDispatched: 751,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _idleStart: 1433278153744,
        parser: [Object],
        ondata: [Function],
        _paused: false,
        _httpMessage: null },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
     _idleStart: 1433278184434,
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
        onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function] },
     ondata: [Function],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _headerSent: false,
        _header: '',
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _expect_continue: true,
        _sent100: true,
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {} } },
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers: 
   { 'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
     host: 'host',
     'content-length': '32697',
     expect: '100-continue',
     'x-forwarded-for': 'ip' },
  trailers: {},
  _pendings: [],
  _pendingIndex: 0,
  url: '/return',
  method: 'POST',
  statusCode: null,
  client: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        reading: true },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        close: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [],
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     onend: [Function],
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 32864,
     _bytesDispatched: 25,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _connections: 2,
        connections: [Getter/Setter],
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _connectionKey: 'ip' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        onend: [Function],
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 1246,
        _bytesDispatched: 751,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _idleStart: 1433278153744,
        parser: [Object],
        ondata: [Function],
        _paused: false,
        _httpMessage: null },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
     _idleStart: 1433278184434,
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
        onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function] },
     ondata: [Function],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _headerSent: false,
        _header: '',
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _expect_continue: true,
        _sent100: true,
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {} } },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  upgrade: false,
  next: [Function: next],
  baseUrl: '',
  originalUrl: '/return',
  _parsedUrl: 
   { protocol: null,
     slashes: null,
     auth: null,
     host: null,
     port: null,
     hostname: null,
     hash: null,
     search: null,
     query: null,
     pathname: '/return',
     path: '/return',
     href: '/return',
     _raw: '/return' },
  params: {},
  query: {},
  res: 
   { domain: null,
     _events: { finish: [Function] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     writable: true,
     _last: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: true,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: true,
     _headerSent: false,
     _header: '',
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: false,
     _hangupClose: false,
     socket: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        onend: [Function],
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 32864,
        _bytesDispatched: 25,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 1433278184434,
        parser: [Object],
        ondata: [Function],
        _paused: false,
        _httpMessage: [Circular] },
     connection: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        onend: [Function],
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 32864,
        _bytesDispatched: 25,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 1433278184434,
        parser: [Object],
        ondata: [Function],
        _paused: false,
        _httpMessage: [Circular] },
     _expect_continue: true,
     _sent100: true,
     _headers: 
      { 'x-powered-by': 'Express',
        'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
        'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE',
        'access-control-allow-headers': 'Content-Type' },
     _headerNames: 
      { 'x-powered-by': 'X-Powered-By',
        'access-control-allow-origin': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
        'access-control-allow-methods': 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
        'access-control-allow-headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' },
     req: [Circular],
     locals: {} },
  secret: undefined,
  cookies: {},
  signedCookies: {},
  body: {},
  route: { path: '/return', stack: [ [Object] ], methods: { post: true } } }
```

Edit 2:
I realized that something wasn't right. So I did some looking and found that Node wasn't even accepting the XML, so I'm using a module that does that and now the body is containing the documents. The only problem is that when I tried to save it, it was corrupted, so I'm working on that.

Comment: The XML has the PDFBytes, so you need access to the `req` or else you aren't going to be able to pull it.

Comment: I can access req, but I might have to output it into a .txt because my console only goes so far. What object is it stored in?

Comment: I threw it into an Answer for you

Answer (score 2):

You have to ensure that attaching Documents to your Connect event is enabled in your DocuSign Connect Settings.

Here's the XML that you'll want to strip the PDFBytes out of and then handle it locally on decoding and saving as a PDF.

```
<DocumentPDFs>
  <DocumentPDF>
    <Name>Sample Document.pdf</Name>
      <PDFBytes>{omitted}</PDFBytes>
      <DocumentType>CONTENT</DocumentType>
  </DocumentPDF>
</DocumentPDFs>
```